# MongoDB Java Geospatial Query where clause

Tags: java, mongodb, command, geospatial

i am using a geospatial query in mongodb java driver to get locations around a given location using the following code:

```
BasicDBObject myCmd = new BasicDBObject(); 

myCmd.append("geoNear", collectionName); 
double[] loc = {5,5}; 
myCmd.append("near", loc); 
myCmd.append("spherical", true); 
myCmd.append("distanceMultiplier", 6378000);
myCmd.append("maxDistance", 200); 

BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList)myResults.get("results");
for( Iterator< Object > it = results.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
{
    BasicDBObject result  = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
    BasicDBObject dbo = (BasicDBObject) result.get("obj");
    System.out.println(dbo.getString("name"));
}
```

This works fine so far. Where im getting into troubles is adding additional selection criteria. i.e. my collection has a field named category and i want to add the category to the query. e.g. give me all locations belonging to a given category.

Looking forward to receive your answers and hints!

BR
Martin

Comment: You have tried myCmd.append("query",categoryDocument) where categoryDocument is a document representing your query, which I think you have to construct as another DBObject. I don't use the Java driver, so can't test. But additional filtering is definitely done via the query field with a document as a parameter.

Comment: hi john, 
this solved my problem!!
thanks a lot!

br
martin

Comment: Add your solution as an answer for other user please.

Comment: @Martin, I have added the solution in case someone else has this question. Feel free to edit it and/or accept it if it helped you and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [geoNear docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) to restrict the geospatial query on some other attributes you add a document as a query parameter.

```
BasicDBObject myCmd = new BasicDBObject(); 
BasicDBObject myQuery = new BasicDBObject();    

myCmd.append("geoNear", collectionName); 
double[] loc = {5,5}; 
myCmd.append("near", loc); 
myCmd.append("spherical", true); 
myCmd.append("distanceMultiplier", 6378000);
myCmd.append("maxDistance", 200); 

//construct a query document from another BasicDBOject
myQuery.append("category":"some category");
//add this as a query document
myCmd.append("query", myQuery);

BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList)myResults.get("results");
for( Iterator< Object > it = results.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
{
    BasicDBObject result  = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
    BasicDBObject dbo = (BasicDBObject) result.get("obj");
    System.out.println(dbo.getString("name"));
}
```